# Is there a way to get the a video file or thumbnail for a video through the linkedin v2 api?

Tags: linkedin-api

We're able to get metadata about videos via the `ugcPosts` endpoint and analytics via `videoAnalytics`, but I'm trying to get the actual video file or a thumbnail of the video.

I'm trying hitting:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/<ID>?fields=id,recipes&oauth2_access_token=XXX&projection=(*,recipes*(*), privatePlayableStreams*(*),playableStreams*(*))`

But the response doesn't have any urls in it:

```
{
    "recipes": [
        {
           "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video-captions-thumbnails",
            "status": "AVAILABLE"
        }
    ],
    "id": "XXX"
}
```

I'm not sure if the data is not available or if I've got the projection wrong or something else.